# How to write Select statement in the Where clause in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm getting the following error when running the below in the snowflake:

> 'Unexpected Select statement'

Here is my SQL

```sql
SELECT * FROM ABC
WHERE DR2NB NOT IN ( SELECT DR2NB FROM ABC WHERE FLAG='TRUE' )
ORDER BY DR2NB
```

Comment: Is this the only query in your session? Often I get this error because I forgot a semicolon and it's picking up the `SELECT` from a different query.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE ABC (DR2NB NUMBER, FLAG VARCHAR);

INSERT INTO ABC VALUES(1,'TRUE'),(2,'FALSE'),(3,'TRUE'),(4,'FALSE'),(1,'TRUE'),(2,'FALSE'),(3,'TRUE'),(4,'FALSE');

SELECT * FROM ABC WHERE DR2NB NOT IN ( SELECT DR2NB FROM ABC WHERE FLAG='TRUE' ) ORDER BY DR2NB;
```

[image: OUTPUT]

You can achieve the desired result by using the below query too:

```
SELECT * FROM ABC WHERE FLAG!='TRUE' ORDER BY DR2NB;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to suggest changes without examples of the data, but I would suggest structuring the subquery like this:

```html
With x as(SELECT DR2NB FROM ABC WHERE FLAG='TRUE' ) 
SELECT * 
FROM ABC 
WHERE 
DR2NB NOT IN x 
ORDER BY DR2NB;
```

Reference:

- https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/constructs/with.html
- https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/operators-subquery.html
- https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/querying-subqueries.html